# how to use jquery validation on multiple fields?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<?php
    <input type='text' name='contact_number[$id]' id='contact_number'>
?>
```

where i an posting multiple contact no in array.  I want to add jquery validation in contact no that it must be required true. but its not working.

My jquery code is :

```
$("#editUserForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "contact_number": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10,
            number: true
        }     
    },
    messages: {    
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the Id is same or input name is same

Comment: Input name is same and will be having different id's. i.e. multiple input.

Answer (score 0):

`"contact_number"` will never match `contact_number[]`, or any other version with an array index.  This plugin just does not work like that.

You can either specify each one exactly within `.validate()`...

```
$("#editUserForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "contact_number[1]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10,
            number: true
        },
        "contact_number[2]": {
            // rules
        }
        ....
```

OR dynamically match all fields that "start with" `contact_number` using `.rules()` method.

```
$('[name^="contact_number"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @sparky.

```
// validate form first
$("form").validate()

$('[name^="contact_number"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    });
});
```

Documentation available at https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/